# Can I use a string as a foreign key in MySQL. I'm using Laravel 8. (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005)

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-8

This is my first table named account_groups,

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('account_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

this is my 2nd table name group_targets

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('group_targets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('group_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('position');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('group_name')
                ->references('name')
                ->on('account_groups')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

when migrating it gives the following error,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `testmyuser`.`group_targets` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `group_targets` add constraint `group_targets_g_name_foreign` foreign key (`G_name`) references `account_groups` (`name`) on delete cascade)
```

Can someone help me with this.?
(I don't know I asked the question correctly. please inform me if the question is not clear)

Comment: name needs to be indexed..

Comment: I'm a newbie. can you please explain?

Comment: please review Conditions and Restrictions here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. And what do you need clarifying ? is that you don't know what an index is? you done't know how to create one? or something else?